# Connecting to remote mongo db

Tags: php, macos, mongodb

This is my connection code

```
$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://172.16.1.133",array("username"=>"username","pass"=>"pass"));
```

This is the error I get

```
Parse Error syntax error unexpected ':' in test.php.
```

When I use local mongo

```
$m = new MongoClient();
```

It works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$conn           = new MongoClient('mongodb://172.16.1.133');
```

//you could try this it works fine.(try do not include username and password just like this)

Comment: What text editor are you using, I used sublime its great